# Issue with In-App purchase on ios9

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios9

On trying to perform a purchase on my app, i keep getting the popup which says "Your Purchase could not be completed. For assistance contact iTunes Support at ..... ".

I had used the same account few minutes back to perform iap and at that time it got processed successfully. I never used to face this issue before upgrading to ios9. Is there some issue with my account or some issue with new upgrade of ios9.
[image]

Comment: Is this from a programming stand point?  Or from a user in an app trying to purchase something?

Comment: so i am seeing reduced iap transactions in my app ever since the rollout of ios9, so was trying to verify it on the device itself. When i did try to do a purchase on the device it started me showing this popup. Not sure why this is happening.. has something changed on the way iap transaction needs to be handled on ios9 ?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the pop-up?  Did you contact iTunes Support?  Does the Apple ID account have funds?

Comment: I think funds isnt a problem since it is latched on to a credit card, so no issues over there.. I have written to iTunes Support but haven't heard back from them yet... Have update the image with the screenshot in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar with my own app and in app purchases. It stopped working in iOS9. 
In my case this was due to Apple's new Apple Transport Security. 
You can disable it altogether by adding this in your info.plist

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Then you will be able to make all the connections as before. although this is not the safest option. you might use this to test if that was the cause of your problem.

Comment: I have already added the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads , but am still getting this issue.. @FilipD did it totally go away in your case ?

Comment: It did go away in my case. I didn't change anything else